# Have Latex tables stopped working?

Tags: support, bug, math-display

In a range of browsers, I've found that $\LaTeX$ tables no longer seem to work on this site. Neither of these posts display correctly:

[How to test for a synergistic effect of A & B with proportions of treatment effects, if I don't have the full 2x2 table?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/142057/if-i-have-a-2x2-table-of-proportions-of-treatment-effects-what-is-the-best-test)

[Significant predictors become non-significant in multiple logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27257/significant-predictors-become-non-significant-in-multiple-logistic-regression/27260#27260)

Were these misformatted in the first place? Their Latex looks okay to me but perhaps they did not display correctly before - I know I have seen some other instances of Latex tables but they may have been constructed differently. Or has support for Latex tables changed?

I can see the same problem on [Maths SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/943539/72968) so it isn't specific to CV.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I don't think LaTeX tables have ever been supported on SE. I've seen *arrays* in the LaTeX maths environment, which look like tables.

Comment: @Scortchi This may well be the case. My memory may be deceiving me, but I am sure I recall seeing "tables" in Latex complete with gridlines. Perhaps they were heavily formatted arrays, or similar - I'm not enough of a Latex wizard to know!

Comment: I always use arrays -- they can include lines; I could never figure out how to get tables to work, and I eventually concluded that they didn't.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think `\begin{table}` has ever worked on the SE system.  (There is a relevant thread on meta.SE from 2009 here: [Why can't table markup elements be used?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16356/187282))  I don't believe it is supported by Mathjax.  To make a "table" in $\LaTeX$ / Mathjax on the SE sites that support it, use `\begin{array}{}... \end{array}`.  I have an example here: [DF for regression SS in multiple linear regression when sigma is known](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/63247/7290), and I discussed the issue on meta.SE here: [Is there any markdown to create tables?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/192843/187282)

Comment: Thanks, I wondered whether those threads had been superseded (I know there have been some changes to rendering) but apparently not - suspect you're right that the posts I found simply never worked, rather than have stopped working recently!