# Best practice for creating tables on Cross Validated?

Tags: discussion, support

I have a question about my Cross Validated post: [Appropriate econometric model for repeated cross sectionals](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/332950/appropriate-econometric-model-for-repeated-cross-sectionals)

I am wondering if someone could please point to some online resource or provide some help below on how to best generate tables on Cross Validated? (I resorted to pasting the tables as pictures in my first question).

Comment: @Tim I reopened this thread in the belief that you might have misinterpreted it.  To me it's clear that it is asking a legitimate question about how to use our site, even though the initial paragraph might suggest otherwise.

Comment: See https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3239/17230